# How to add a linefeed after a hidden password input when using `read -s`

Tags: bash, curl

When executing a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -I \
  -u $(read -p "`echo $'\n'`User: "; echo $REPLY):$(read -s -p "`echo $'\n'`Pass: "; echo $REPLY;) \
  https://example.com \
  -s
```

the password is hidden (wanted), but the cURL output starts within the password line (not wanted), e.g.:

```
User: a
Pass: HTTP/2 200
content-encoding: gzip
```

How to achieve that the cURL output does start in the line below the password line?

```
User: a
Pass: 
HTTP/2 200
content-encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `read` before the [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) call. Not only do you have better control over where newlines are put, it also makes it easier to read the code.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "User: " user
read -rsp "Pass: " pass
echo

curl -I https://example.com -s -K- <<< "-u $user:$pass"
```

Passing the username and password via `stdin` has the added benefit that you do not pass the username and password as arguments to the script which may be observed by someone who should not have this information.

Comment: Thank you, didn't even know the `-K` flag so far :)